# My screen is glitchy get after upgrade to latest kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

Okay I upgraded my kernel from (4.4.something) to 4.8 and now when I boot ubuntu I am welcomed by a low-res gnome ubuntu loading screen (I have gnome instead of unity on ubuntu 16.04.2 ). Now as I said the screen just glitches and I'm not in the desktop I am in the terminal where I can't type anything to do anything. That's my problem can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Need some more info, primarily: what graphics card are you using?

Comment: @Termhn I am using an Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT . There were no problems before the kernel upgrade.